# json файл с id городов openweathermap скачивается кракозябрами

Tags: json, api, openweathermap

![screenImage]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn8AE.png Мне нужно скачать json файл с openweathermap, первый из списка вот на этой странице http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/
Он скачивается, но в неправильной кодировке... Я пробовал в ворде в настройках порыться, не помогло. В нотпаде преобразовать в utf-8 тоже безрезультатно... 
Дело в моём компе или всё-таки в самом файле? Помогите, пожалуйста :))

Как его тогда правильно открыть? (да, я настолько тормоз:))

Comment: Да нормально вроде открывается, тем же NPP, например... он же утверждает, что это обычный UTF8 без BOM...

Comment: Расширение же `.gz`, это архивы gzip.

Answer (score 1):

Я понял в чем твоя проблема. Это архивы. Открой их простым winrar`ом и будет тебе счастье